# TensorFlow: offset when rotating image and points by a random angle

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an image and 3 points. I want to rotate the image and the points together. To this end, I rotate the image by some angle *a* and the points by the same angle.
When *a* is fixed to a python scalar (say pi/3), the rotation works fine (cf. image below, the blue dots are on the dark squares).

[image]

When the angle is randomly chosen with `angle = tf.random_uniform([])`, there is an offset between the rotated image and the rotated points.

[image]

Below is a the full code reproducing this behaviour.

My question is: how to explain this behaviour and correct it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create toy image
square = np.zeros((1, 800, 800, 3))
square[:, 100:400, 100:400] = 1
square[:, 140:180, 140:180] = 0
square[:, 240:280, 240:280] = 0
square[:, 280:320, 280:320] = 0
kp = np.array([[160, 160], [260, 260], [300, 300]])
kp = np.expand_dims(kp, axis=0)

def _rotate(image, keypoints, angle, keypoints_num):
    image = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, angle)
    cos, sin = tf.cos(angle), tf.sin(angle)
    x0, y0  = .5, .5
    rot_mat = tf.Variable([[cos, -sin], [sin, cos]], trainable=False)
    keypoints -= (x0, y0)
    keypoints = tf.reshape(keypoints, shape=[-1, 2])
    keypoints = tf.matmul(keypoints, rot_mat)
    keypoints = tf.reshape(keypoints, shape=[-1, keypoints_num, 2])
    keypoints += (x0, y0)
    return image, keypoints


image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 800, 800, 3])
keypoints = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3, 2])

angle = np.pi / 3 # fix angle, works fine
#angle = tf.random_uniform([]) # random angle, does not work
image_r, keypoints_r = _rotate(image, keypoints / 800, angle, 3)
keypoints_r *= 800

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

imr, kr = sess.run([image_r, keypoints_r], feed_dict={image: square, keypoints:kp})

# displaying output
plt.imshow(imr[0])
plt.scatter(*zip(*kr[0]))
plt.savefig('rotation.jpg')
```

Comment: Kudos for the fully reproducible and standalone question, without depending on any external image files.

Comment: @jdehesa why it does not work when the image is not square? Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
rot_mat = tf.Variable([[cos, -sin], [sin, cos]], trainable=False)
```

Since `rot_mat` is a variable, its value is being set only when variables are initialized, here:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

So at that point `rot_mat` gets some value (using `cos` and `sin`, which in turn depend on `angle`, which is random) and it does not change anymore. Then when you do:

```
imr, kr = sess.run([image_r, keypoints_r], feed_dict={image: squares, keypoints:kps})
```

It is a different call to `run`, so `tf.random_uniform` produces a new value, but `rot_mat` still keeps the same value from when it was initialized. Since the image is rotated with:

```
image = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, angle)
```

And the key points are rotated with:

```
keypoints = tf.matmul(keypoints, rot_mat)
```

The rotations do not match. The easiest fix is not to use a variable for `rot_mat`:

```
rot_mat = [[cos, -sin], [sin, cos]]
```

With this, the code works fine. If you really need `rot_mat` to be a variable, it is possible, but it is a bit more of work and it does not seem to be needed here. If you do not like `rot_mat` being a list and want to have a proper tensor instead, you can use `tf.convert_to_tensor`:

```
rot_mat = tf.convert_to_tensor([[cos, -sin], [sin, cos]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and thorough explanation, it works fine with your fix!

Comment: @BiBi, why It does not work if the image is not square? see second answer